# Show that $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots)=\frac{1}{n!n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots)=\frac{1}{n!n}$, (here $n$ is a natural number)

Maybe easy, but I cannot see it.

Thanks in advance!
Alexander

Comment: What is the sum $1+q+q^2+q^3+\dotsb$ for $\lvert q\rvert < 1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{n+1}\right)^k=\frac1{1-\frac1{n+1}}\ldots$$

Comment: Ok, I can solve it now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since $$1+x+x^2+\cdots=\frac1{1-x}$$

Therefore,

$$1+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\cdots=\frac1{1-\frac1{n+1}}=\frac1{\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n}$$

Now,

$$\frac1{(n+1)!}\cdot(1+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\cdots)=\frac1{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac1{n!n}$$