# Rudin 3.31 bound on e

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In the second photo, what is the justification for

$$
<\frac{1}{(n+1) !}\left\{1+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}+\cdots\right\}=\frac{1}{n ! n}
$$

I feel that the inequality and equal sign should be reversed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Factor $1/(n+1)!$ out of each term.  What is left if a bunch of terms of the form $$\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)\dotsb(n+k)}. $$
What can you say about the relation between this fraction and $1/(n+2)^{k}$?  What does this say about $1/(n+1)^k$?

Comment: Ok I understand why we factor out $1/(n+1)!$ how did you combine all of the $1+\frac{1}{n+1}\dots$ into a single fraction?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039516/question-on-rudin-theorem-3-31-proof

Comment: And also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497429/show-that-frac1n11-frac1n1-frac1n12-frac1n13 .